# Cannot install Visio Professional 2013 after installing Office Professional Plus 2013

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, 64-bit, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

On a freshly installed Windows 8.1 (x64) computer, I successfully installed Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 (x64). I then proceeded to install Microsoft Visio Professional 2013 (x64) [all of these things, the OS, Office and Visio, are in Chinese Simplified]. However, when I try to install Visio, it says that a file in the installation CD has been corrupted and it asks me to use another disk.

Then, I tried to use the same "defective" CD to install Visio on a Windows 8.1 (virtual) computer that does not have Office Professional Plus on. This time, it successfully installs Visio and there is no indication that an error has occured!

All of the above software is MSDN VL software. I could not find a solution anywhere else on the Internet.

Comment: Have you applied all the existing Office 2013 (and Windows) updates before trying to install Visio?  Why not call MS? Installation support is free in most cases.

Comment: Yes, I did apply all updates possible (including the Service Pack).

Comment: If you installed an Office service pack then then you may need a Visio installer that has SP1 integrated already... but that's just a guess. :)

Comment: Thanks, but it is of no use whatsoever.

Comment: So you did try a Visio disk that has SP1 integrated already?

Comment: Yes, I did. It failed.

Comment: Have you tried to install directly from the internet (or ISO-file)? Maybe your disk IS actually corrupted (in the part of integration with the existing office).

Comment: Thank you for the support you have provided me! It turns out a trick that I used worked. Here is how: I told you about how it installed perfectly on a virtual computer. I used the MSOCache files on the "good" computer to install Visio and Project on the "defective" computer.